# How to check if a "nonce" number is already taken?

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

I have an API endpoint, which creates and sends a few transactions in strict sequence. Because I don't wait for results of these transactions, I specify a nonce number for each of them to execute them in the right order.

This endpoint is built using AWS Lambda function. So, if I have many concurrent requests, the lambda runs in concurrent mode. In this case, several concurrent instances can get the same nonce (I'm using `eth.getTransactionCount` method to get the latest transaction count) and send a few transactions with the same nonce. Therefore, I receive errors because instead of creating a new transaction, it tries to replace an existing one.

Basically, I need a way to check if a nonce is already taken right before the transaction sending or somehow reserve a nonce number (is it even possible?).

Answer (score 5):

The web3 [getTransactionCount()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactioncount) only returns the amount of already mined transactions, but there's currently no way to return the highest **pending** nonce (for an address) using web3.

So you'll need to store your pending nonces in a separate DB (e.g. Redis). Each Lambda run will need to access this DB to get the highest pending nonce, calculate one that it's going to be using (probably just +1), and store this number to the DB so that other instances can't use it anymore.

Mind that it's recommended to implement a lock ([Redis](https://redis.io/topics/distlock), [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-distributed-locks-with-the-dynamodb-lock-client/)) to prevent multiple app instances from accessing the DB and claiming the same value at the same time.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears you *can* check the pending block by adding the "pending" block tag as the second argument, e.g. `getTransactionCount(address, "pending")`. However, that won't make the RPC call more reliable (i.e. it's still necessary to track nonce locally).

Comment: @jake This is a very good observation. And I wasn't sure, so I just tested it with a sender [address](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc11e68f50b554c4007c276410820d58084b0452f) that seems to have a stuck pending [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8d7d91d6fb6608a858ecdecfd2eabad559f0755ebb61fc9a15ec2a5eecaffea4) at the moment... But the `pending` value does not return the sum of **"mined + pending"** outgoing transactions (in this case 4; 3 mined and 1 pending). It still only returns the amount of **mined** outgoing transactions at the time of the "pending" block (in this case 3).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think that's an important disambiguation - there's really two different kinds of pending we're talking about here (pending block vs pending tx's).  Since it's talking about the latter, this answer is indeed correct as is.

Answer (score 4):

> Basically, I need a way to check if a nonce is already taken right before the transaction sending or somehow reserve a nonce number (is it even possible?).

You should not.

Instead, you should manage nonce in your internal database (SQL, etc.) which provides atomic counters and multiple readers and writers. You only rely to the network provided nonce if 1) your system has failed 2) you need to manually reset it.

[Here is an example code for Web3.py and SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/miohtama/sto/blob/master/sto/models/broadcastaccount.py#L10).